# Android: Why doesn't custom button theme apply to dialogs?

Tags: android, themes, android-alertdialog

So I'm using an application-wide theme which implements a custom button set. The custom buttons show up just fine in all of the app's activities. One activity however, calls an alert dialog which contains two buttons. Unfortunately, the custom button theme refuses to apply itself here.

I understand that I could just implement another activity in place of the alert dialog, which mimics its functions, but it just seems illogical that I should have to do this.

What I don't understand, is why my theme does not apply to the alert dialog as well. What gives a dialog the privilege to avoid an app-wide theme?

Comment: Hmm..well I may or may not have found the answer to my question. After re-reading through the AlertDialog.Builder documentation, I noticed this in the constructors section:

"The actual theme that an AlertDialog uses is a private implementation"

I also noticed that the AlertDialog.Builder Constructor which **does** support the theme argument is not supported until API Level 11. Does this answer my own question?

Answer (score 2):

please see this blog:
http://podlesek.org/blog/blogpost/android-how-replace-default-buttons-including-those-dialogs